# Function pointer doesn't assign into array of function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

After all typdefs are removed, I have the following declarations:

```
class Message {
  protected:
    Message* (*factories[N])(HardwareSerial);
    ...
}

class DebugMessage : Message {
  protected:
    Message* receive(HardwareSerial serial);
    ...
  public:
    DebugMessage(char* message);
    ...
};

Message* DebugMessage::receive(HardwareSerial serial){...}

DebugMessage::DebugMessage(char* message){
  ...
  factories[DEBUG_MESSAGE] = &DebugMessage::receive;
  ...
}
```

However when I attempt to compile it I get an error on the assignment stating

```
debugMessage.cpp: In constructor ‘DebugMessage::DebugMessage(char*)’:
debugMessage.cpp:4:28: error: cannot convert ‘Message* (DebugMessage::*)(HardwareSerial)’ to ‘Message* (*)(HardwareSerial)’ in assignment
   factories[DEBUG_MESSAGE] = &DebugMessage::receive;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be more specific about the **exact** type of the function pointer you need to store in your array:

```
class Message {
  protected:
    Message* (DebugMessage::*factories[N])(HardwareSerial);
    ...
}
```

*UPDATE* (a bit more details)

The reason for that data type clarification is that member functions have an extra (hidden) first parameter `this` which the compiler has to know about when making a call to it via the function pointer.

Having said that I must point out that `static` member functions do not have that restriction (since they don't have the `this` parameter) and can be "freely mixed" with free functions in that regard

Comment: Corrcet: pointers to free functions and pointers to member functions are different types.

Answer (score 1):

@YePhlcK explained why you're having the problem but I don't know that the code he posted really solves the issue. I think you'll only be able to add pointers to `DebugMessage` member functions as factories using that. I've modified your code so it compiles and uses [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to get a function pointer to a member function.

```
#include <functional>

class HardwareSerial {};

class Message {
public:
    using Reciever = Message*(HardwareSerial);
protected:
    std::function<Reciever> factories[10];
};

class DebugMessage : Message {
protected:
    Message* receive(HardwareSerial serial);
public:
    DebugMessage(char* message);
};

Message* DebugMessage::receive(HardwareSerial serial){ return nullptr; }

DebugMessage::DebugMessage(char* message){
    factories[0] = std::bind(&DebugMessage::receive, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

This way you can have member and non-member functions in your array as well as lambdas and function objects. You only need to use `std::bind` with the member functions.

Comment: These were both really good answers. If anyone were to find this question I would recommend them to code in this manner. That being said, I picked the other answer because it directly answered the question I had (even if it's a less correct way to code).